# PHP: Call a function at the beginning and end of each file

Tags: php, debugging

I'd like to automatically call a user defined function at the beginning and end of each file. This would include the script being requested as well as each include within that script.

The purpose of this is to create a debugging tool that will log the time it takes for each file to execute. The microtime at the start and end of each file will be stored to report the results at the end of script execution.

[edit]
I spent some time looking at xhprof & xdebug

Xdebug wont work since I cannot toggle it on and off at runtime (Our current debugging system allows us to pass an attribute in the URL, which turns on/off debugging as a session variable, ultimately displaying the profiling data in the bottom of the page after load - this is very useful)

Xhprof is closer, though it doesn't allow me to break up each function call, nor pass additional debug information to be attached to the profiling element. For example, I have a mysql query user defined function that I use for all my queries - I'd like to pass the actual query to the profile element so I can identify heavier vs lighter queries in the page (I know I can log queries too, just wanted to demonstrate how I could benefit from this requirement). Another example would be attaching incoming, outgoing function data and any other debug information I would like to track to the profile element.

Currently I manually track start, end times, additional debugging info by placing lines of code in every function that send the data to a common function, hold it in a global variable and spit it out as debugging data following the script output. I extend this to scripts, templates, etc. This manual entry of the data in every function, script, template is what I am hoping to avoid. I expect it will need to be done for some of the data unique to each function, but the repeated stuff (start, end time) should not have to be entered in every stinking query lol.

Comment: Have you looked at the php.ini auto_prepend and auto_append directives?

Comment: Which SAPI are you using? Apache? CGI? CLI? That will make a difference in the methodology.

Comment: The functionality - as you describe it - will only work in case of strictly linear execution of the request: i.e. all the files provide independent output and do not depend on the results of previously included files. If you still insist on what you've described, then you better emphasize this - and expect answers with ready tools or overriding implementations of  `require` or `include` function

Comment: It's been a  while since I played with php's streams, but if php lets you muck with the default stream and apply a custom filter to it, then you might be able to inject code. If you're really lucky include will use your default modified stream.

Comment: @ Mark Baker: That would take care of the script, but not the includes, functions.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the responses!

@ Levi Morrison: LAMP RHEL

@ Max Yakimets: I expect that the outer calls would include the proc time of the inner calls. Overriding require, include may be part of the answer. Still functions need to be addressed.

@ rdlawrey: I am going to play with Xdebug and see if that does what I need. Surprised I haven't heard of it before - guess there's a first time for everyone to learn about new tool!

@ Rambo Coder: I guess that's kinda what I'm asking the community

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd highly recommend checking out [Xdebug](http://xdebug.org/) instead to help you debug your code. Doing this yourself is just going to drive you nuts!

Xdebug can do [function traces](http://xdebug.org/docs/execution_trace) out of the box and much more.

For example:

```
// start tracing function calls to file
xdebug_start_trace('/path/to/trace_file.txt');
// your code here
xdebug_stop_trace();
```

Comment: Xdebug is helpful, but I feel like this might be better suited as a comment? It doesn't really answer the question and is basically just a link :)

Comment: @rdlowrey Fair enough, usage example added.

Comment: This may be the answer. I'm going to dig in tonight and see. Thanks!

Comment: Can't use Xdebug since it cannot be toggled on/off at runtime :(. See my edit above.

Comment: @MarkWexler Not true, you can selectively enable tracing; it even has support for [automatic triggering](http://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#profiler_enable_trigger)

Comment: @Jack I'd like it to by a session variable triggered by a URL variable. So if the url trigger is passed AND the user is qualified (site admin as per user table in db) then the session variable is turned on and profiling will continue as the user navigates through the site. The profiling information will be visible and tacked on to the end of the page output. Can xdebug be triggered by a session variable instead of a get (url) var?

Answer (score 2):

#### Command-line:

This is pretty awesome:

```
echo <file_to_execute> | php \
  -B '$start = microtime(true);' \
  -E '$stop = microtime(true); echo $stop-$start;'
```

This uses two options that are hardly used in PHP, `-B` and `-E`.  The first option lets you specify code that will be run before processing `stdin`, in this case, the file we want to execute.  The second option lets you specify code that will be run once the file is finished.

#### Boring php.ini settings:

Additionally you can set `auto_prepend_file` and `auto_append_file` to do the same thing. I mention it here for completeness, but changing `.ini` settings for this kind of thing feels wrong, though I have no proof that it is bad.

#### Profiling hotspots:

If you've identified a script that is running slowly, you can figure out where you are spending most of your time by using [xhprof](https://github.com/facebook/xhprof).  It's a tool developed at Facebook but is now open-sourced. It is available as a [PECL extension](http://pecl.php.net/package/xhprof) which helps cut down on the installation pain.

#### Real Debugging:

[XDebug](http://xdebug.org/) is an amazing tool that lets you step through your code line-by-line, function-by-function and can do all sorts of things. If you are simply timing code execution, then I wouldn't use XDebug, but if you are really trying to debug code then this extension is your best friend.

---

#### Regarding your edit:

I think you are doing this all wrong.  You really need two environments: a live server and a development one.  The live server doesn't have xhprof or xdebug but the development server has what is needed.

Comment: That doesn't work for scripts that are included from the main script though.

Comment: @Jack Fair, but at least in my mind that doesn't matter. Why would I want to time how long it took to parse each include file?  There *shouldn't* be any executable code, just definitions.  You'd get the overall time it takes for the file to run, including loading ALL files.

Comment: In my mind it doesn't either, but who knows what lurks in those include files ;-)

Comment: Close, but not exactly what I want. Love to do this all in one tool, and spit out the results at the end of the page output. See edits above.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `php.ini` file's `auto_prepend_file` and `auto_append_file` options. Point them to a file that does the timing thing in Iqbal's answer.

Comment: afaik that only works for the first script that's called by php, not code that's included

Comment: Unfortunately that does not cover functions nor included scripts. Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Xdebug, there's [XHProf](http://techportal.inviqa.com/2009/12/01/profiling-with-xhprof/) which is really good and easy to use.

Comment: XHprof is closer to what I wan than xdebug, mainly because it can be toggled on/off in runtime, but it still misses some key elements: passing additional data to the profile element, breaking apart the functions (since data on all calls to same function is aggregated into one profile element, I can't tell if certain executions of a function are problematic due to different conditions). See my edit above for more info.

Comment: I use it by focusing on the 'exclusive wall time' combined with the number (or percentage) of total calls. This finds bottlenecks really fast and puts emphasis by comparing parts of your application code against each other. If you need to compare requests, create an automatic mock suite/acceptance test of going through intensive and less intensive logic, and compare the xhprof output for those to runs. (The comparison view of xhprof can tell you what function calls that grew faster.)

Answer (score 0):

$time_start = microtime(true); // put at the start of web page

// Your PHP code

echo microtime(true) - $time_start; // put at the end of web page

Comment: Correct. This is what I already do. I want to avoid having to place this code in every script, function ,etc.

Answer (score 0):

How about writing a little require function?

In `index.php`, you could do `<?php require('requirer.php'); myRequirer(array('script1', 'script2'));`

Then in `requirer.php`:

```
<?php

require('file_with_logger_function');
function requirer($requireFiles)
{
    my_logger_function();
    foreach($requireFiles as $fileName) {
        require($fileName.'.php');
    }
    my_logger_function();
}
```